# Python function to get the co-ordinate pair of a point

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, geolocation, geopy

I am trying to geocode a point shape. But first I want to determine the coordinate pair of the point shapefile before geocoding. The error I get is: 
`**ERROR** :ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point`

```
redshape = fiona.open("murt.shp")
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-ride")
location = geolocator.reverse(redshape)
print(location.address)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `geolocator.reverse()` method is expecting a `Point` obejct or a tuple with two coordinates. However, you are passing `redshape`, which is a `fiona.collection.Collection` object with all the features in your shapefile. You have to iterate through the collection, extract the coordinates and then call the geolocator. Here is an example:

```py
import fiona
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

redshape = fiona.open("murt.shp")
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my-ride")

for feature in redshape:
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']  # here is the x, y pair of coordinates
    location = geolocator.reverse(coords)
    print(location.address)
```

As have you already pointed out, the order of the coordinates for the `geolocator.reverse()` method is y,x and not x,y as I initially thought. Keeping this in mind, you can unpack the x and y values individually and pass them in a specific order. Note that they are still passed inside a tuple.

```py
x, y = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
location = geolocator.reverse((y, x))
```

Comment: hi, the  location = geolocator.reverse(coords) always outputted no location because co-ordinates are on x,y instead of y,x. any idea how i can reverse that

Comment: @rachel I forgot you must pass the coordinates in that order to `geolocator`. Check the edit I just made.

Comment: ok, please i have a question to ask. i have to point shapefile representing towns within a state and i want find the distance between them. so my question is since points are in different shapefile how do i merge them so they would be in the same shapefile before computing the linestring or is it possible to compute the linestring without merging both point shapefiles

Comment: If you don't want to use something like ArcGIS or QGIS to merge the shapefiles beforehand, you can open them with Python (*e.g.* `geopandas`) and merge them in memory before calculating the linestring. Before going into more detail, I encourage you to ask this as a new question (if you don't find anything similar on this site, of course) as it is a completely different question from the original.

Comment: ok thanks i will do that